# Disable first two column move in handsontable

Tags: handsontable

I use handsontable table and have 5 columns in it, with **manualColumnMove** is **true**, so user can move column.

But I want disable this feature for first two columns, how I can do this ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In handsontable 0.34.0 it is possible to prevent row or column moves by returning `false` from the [`beforeColumnMove` hook/callback](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.34.0/Hooks.html#event:beforeColumnMove).

I've adjusted [Joakim Si Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6574956/joakim-si-ali)'s fiddle accordingly:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  var
    data1 = [
      ['', 'Kia', 'Nissan', 'Toyota', 'Honda', 'Mazda', 'Ford'],
      ['2012', 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16],
      ['2013', 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16],
      ['2014', 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16],
      ['2015', 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16],
      ['2016', 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16]
    ],
    container1 = document.getElementById('example1'),
    settings1 = {
      data: data1,
      manualColumnMove: true,
      beforeColumnMove: beforeColumnMove(),
      colHeaders: true,
    },
    hot1;

  hot1 = new Handsontable(container1, settings1);

  function beforeColumnMove() {
    return function(columnsMoving, target) {
      if (columnsMoving[0] < 2 || target < 2) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handsontable/0.34.0/handsontable.full.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handsontable/0.34.0/handsontable.full.min.js"></script>
<div id="example1" class="hot handsontable"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to prevent moving column in beforeColumnMove, example :

```
function setBeforeColumnMove() {
    return function(startColumn, endColumn) {
        var manualColumnMove = this.getPlugin("ManualColumnMove");

        if(startColumn < 2 || endColumn < 2) {
            manualColumnMove.changeColumnPositions(endColumn, startColumn);
        }
    }
};
```

Look this example : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsiali_sixmon/c3p77kox/)

Good luck ;)